# How to Get the Mid Value From List in VB .NET

Tags: vb.net, list, sorting

I have simple loop where I am storing values to my list. I want to get the mid value of that list.

Here is how I am doing it:

```
Dim listOfValues As New List(Of Double)
For i = 1 To 5
    Values.Add(i)
Next

Values.Sort()

' How can I get the Mid Value of That List and store it into some other variable

Dim midValue = Values.mid() ' Something like this
```

How can I get the Mid Value from That List?
I want it to work with both odd and even values of the loop.

Comment: What is the mid value in case of an even number of items?

Comment: What is the *mid value* in your view? Is it related to the value of the *numbers* contained in the collection, or the number of items? In this case, what if the collection contains 4 items instead of 5? Which one is the *middle item*?

Comment: @Jimi By mid value i mean the normal function of mathematic how to find the mid of the loop i.e. number of iteration and then return the value at that index

Comment: @TimSchmelter in case of even number what we have to do is we have to find the average of the two numbers and then we have to add the flor function I guess there

Comment: Do you mean `dim avg = listOfValues.Average(function(x) x)`? Then search the first number that is above this value and take the value at the previous index? -- Note that your code uses two names for the same list.

Comment: @Jimi what i am trying to do is in this case i want to get the values at index(3) i.e. neglecting the first two and last two values from the list

Comment: Well, it's still not clear whether the *middle item* is related to the values in the list of just the number of items. In this case, it's just `dim midItem = listOfValues(listOfValues.Count \ 2)`

Comment: The value you want would usually be referred to as the [median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in case of even number what we have to do is we have to find the
> average of the two numbers and then we have to add the floor function

You can use math to calculate the mid-index and mid-value:

```
Dim midValue As Double = 0
Dim midIndex As Int32 = listOfValues.Count \ 2 ' integer division operator
If listOfValues.Count > 0
    If listOfValues.Count Mod 2 = 0
        ' even number, calculate the midValue from average of 2 in middle
        midValue = (listOfValues(midIndex) + listOfValues(midIndex-1)) \ 2
    Else
        midValue = listOfValues(midIndex)
    End If
End If
```

As commented i'm using the integer division operator `\` to get the integer value of a double(the remainder is truncated) which is simular to `Math.Floor`.